# How to handle unexpected exceptions in JAX-RS

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

My technology stack is Tomcat (servlet 3.0), Jersey for JAX-RS, Spring and Hibernate. When something unexpect goes wrong like some data conversion error in Hibernate, I do not want the clients to see my stacktrace for those exceptions that the Tomcat tries to print by default. However I would like to log those exceptions so I can find what is wrong and fix things.

My first try was using ExceptionMapper from JAX-RS and naively thinking that would solve my problems. But then I noticed that Jersey throws it's own exceptions for example urls that are not mapped are com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundExceptions. This causes 404 exceptions to be logged which I don't want. Worse, the client no longer gets 404 but a status code 500.

I could just create exception mappers for the exceptions that jersey throws but I could miss something. Is there a best practice for something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All exceptions thrown directly by Jersey are subclasses of WebApplicationException, so if you want to catch them all just create an ExceptionMapper for that class and you'll be good.

Comment: What do I do in the ExceptionMapper? Do I have to duplicate the JAX-RS implementation of what is done with WebApplicationExceptions?

Comment: Okay never mind that. I read the source for WebApplicationException and looks like it will always have a proper Response object so I can just return that in the ExceptionMapper.

Comment: Yes you can, although bear in mind that this will give the standard Jersey response which is a full HTML page and may well not be what you want to return, especially if you're using Jersey as an API server rather than directly serving pages.  You can pick the Response apart for the basic information that you need and reformat it as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-core/trap.html. It explains how you can/should catch all runtime exceptions in a web application. Suggested solution with `ExceptionMapper` will only catch JAX-RS exceptions, which is not enough, especially if you're using DB and Hibernate.

Source code of the `ExceptionTrap` class is [here](https://github.com/yegor256/rexsl/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rexsl/core/ExceptionTrap.java).

Comment: I actually went with this solution in the end. While jgm solution worked, this seemed more "correct".

Comment: It's a less Jersey-like way of doing things but still valid.  If you wanted to catch everything then you could have just created an ExceptionMapper for Exception and it would have caught everything, and still have all of the Jersey features of Reponses and the like.

Comment: This solution worked for me for a little while but in the end I had to get rid of it because you lose the original HttpRequest object. I don't know why this felt more right at the time... I've changed the accepted answer to jgm's