# Catching unhanded exceptions with JAX RS

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs, resteasy

JAX-RS offers a nice way to wrap exceptions by using `ExceptionMapper`'s.
But this works only if exceptions occur in my application. But sometimes exception might happen even before my app gets called (e.g. in case client supplies an garbage value of "Accept" header). In this case IllegalAgrumentException happens even before my REST controller is called.
Is there a way to catch such exceptions too?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException>` ? I remember implementing it in such a way, and I think it was catching everything. Though I used `Jersey` and `Guice`, I guess it should be the same.

Comment: @AlexP I tried and it didn't help :( Probably your runtime exceptions were thrown from your servlet code or at least after your servlet received control.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14565256) might help.

Comment: @vyakhir, I am also facing with same problem, let me know if you have got any solution.

Comment: @kswaughs, As I remember no, I didn't find any elegant solution. That's why I'm not a fan of JAX RS since then.
Next time I need to implement a REST service, I will look towards Spring REST.